# Editing the Wordpress Footer Widgets Section

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm currently working on a Wordpress site, using the Rhythm theme - it's default template has four columns built into the footer, and I'd like to only have three.

So in my child theme, I went into the widget section and removed a column from the php code, so it looks like this:

```
if (ts_get_opt('footer-widgets-enable') == 1): ?>
<!-- Divider -->
<hr class="mt-0 mb-0"/>
<!-- End Divider -->

<!-- Widgets Section -->
<section class="footer-sidebar page-section">
    <div class="container relative">
        <div class="row multi-columns-row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <?php if (is_active_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-1', 'footer-sidebar-1') )): ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-1', 'footer-sidebar-1') ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <?php if (is_active_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-2', 'footer-sidebar-2') )): ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-2', 'footer-sidebar-2') ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
                <?php if (is_active_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-3', 'footer-sidebar-3') )): ?>
                    <?php dynamic_sidebar( ts_get_custom_sidebar('footer-3', 'footer-sidebar-3') ); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!-- End Widgets Section -->
```

The problem I'm having is that the page is still referencing the code with four columns instead. So I'm guessing my issue is in my footer.php file, or the template-parts.php file and that it's not pointing to the proper file.

My biggest concern is that I didn't set up my child theme correctly, and now the coding is trying to reference two different themes.

Comment: The child theme is active, but I'm thinking it's inheriting some actions.

Comment: Why don't you drag the fourth column to the deactivated widgets section in the admin area?

Comment: For tracking the theme, u just remove the 4 th one code in your main theme and check whether it coming or not. If it is not coming you can check your child theme set up.